# How to add +1 or -1 to a number

Tags: math, lua

I'm working on a script where I need to switch number from plus to minus or otherwise, and add +1 or -1 according to if it's minus or plus. now I know I can check with `if vx < 0 then ...` 
but how can I do it with mathematical formula?

This is what i've tried, but it worked out only for +

```
vx = (vx + (vx/vx)) * (-1)
```

Comment: Is there an absolute value function? Your equation is close, but needs to be `vx = (vx + (abs(vx)/vx)) * (-1)` (or whatever the absolute value function is).

Comment: math.abs, yep thanks a lot. you can write it as an answer, i would accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is close, but needs the absolute value:

```
vx = (vx + (math.abs(vx)/vx)) * (-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vx = (vx + (vx < 0 and -1 or 1)) * (-1)
```

Equivalent to a piecewise function in mathematics.